# Python - Plot a graph with times on x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I have the following dataframe in pandas:

```
dfClicks = pd.DataFrame({'clicks': [700,800,550],'date_of_click': ['10/25/1995 
03:30','10/25/1995 04:30','10/25/1995 05:30']})

dfClicks['date_of_click'] = pd.to_datetime(dfClicks['date_of_click'])

dfClicks.set_index('date_of_click')

dfClicks.clicks = pd.to_numeric(dfClicks.clicks)
```

Could you please advise how I can plot the above such that the x-axis shows the date/time and the y axis the number of clicks? I will also need to plot another data frame which includes predicted clicks on the same graph, just to compare. The test could be a replica of above, with minor changes:

```
dfClicks2 = pd.DataFrame({'clicks': [750,850,500],'date_of_click': ['10/25/1995 
    03:30','10/25/1995 04:30','10/25/1995 05:30']})

dfClicks2['date_of_click'] = pd.to_datetime(dfClicks2['date_of_click'])

dfClicks2.set_index('date_of_click')

dfClicks2.clicks = pd.to_numeric(dfClicks2.clicks)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to numeric the column `clicks` and then:

```
ax = dfClicks.plot()
dfClicks2.plot(ax=ax)
ax.legend(["Clicks","Clicks2"])
```

Output:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
There is an error in how you set the index, change

```
dfClicks.set_index('date_of_click')
```

with:

```
dfClicks = dfClicks.set_index('date_of_click')
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed clicks to number, but when I run your code, I get the error ValueError: view limit minimum -35995.911458333336 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units

Comment: I changed the years to 2000 as well, in case it was causing problems

Comment: I updated the answer, where you can see how I created the dataframe. Can you post here the code that you used to convert to numeric? The code that is giving you the ValueError. Thanks! Try with this: `dfClicks.clicks = pd.to_numeric(dfClicks.clicks)`

Comment: Please see the updated code above. I still get the same error.

Comment: I found out what your problem was, check the updated answer. now it should work!

Comment: Thanks for finding the problem